# TextView problems on Samsung devices

Tags: android, textview

For some reason the font color will only display default grey on samsung devices.  It was running fine, then for some reason it went grey on just the samsung stuff (tablet and phone).  Does anyone know why and how I can fix it?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/agaent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entradas  Aperitivos"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />
```

Comment: Give color code in android:textColor hopefully you will fix it.

Comment: i should had mentioned that I tried the hex code, then changing the colors,.  It is so strange that it worked fine then it went default grey on the entire app, but only on the devices and not on the emulator.